# I want to use Python to unzip the zip file and save it in each folder.?

Tags: python

would like to create each folder and store the data to decompress the folder.
Like the picture.
[image]

this is my code

```
for path in glob.glob(curdir + '/data/*.zip'):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(path) as zfile:
        zfile.extractall(os.path.dirname(path))
```

I'm curious about how to change the contents of zfile.extractall(?) here.

Comment: what do you mean "change the contents of `zfile.extractall(?)`? What does it do now and what do you want it to do?

Comment: The code is now unzip in the data folder. As shown in the question photo, I am curious about how to unzip the zip.

Comment: @joshmeranda as I understand it, the question is: given the path to the `.zip` file found via `glob.glob`, how to create the corresponding destination folder name for unzipping?

Answer (score 0):

Remove only `.zip` from `path` - ie.

```py
zfile.extractall( path.replace('.zip', '') )
```

or

```py
zfile.extractall( path.rsplit('.', 1)[0] )


zfile.extractall( os.path.splitext(path)[0] )
```

---

Full code:

```py
#import os
import glob
import zipfile

curdir = '.'

for path in glob.glob(curdir + '/data/*.zip'):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(path) as zfile:
        zfile.extractall( path.replace('.zip', '') )
        #zfile.extractall( path.rsplit('.', 1)[0] )
        #zfile.extractall( os.path.splitext(path)[0] )
```