# I want to create a folder named after a specific name using python

Tags: python

I want to create a folder named after a specific name. Like in the picture (a folder with only numbers except for .zip).
[image]

here is my code.

```
import os
import glob
import zipfile
import sys


p_dir =  './data/'

for file in os.listdir(p_dir):
    file_name = file
    oldname = str(file_name)
    newname1 = file.split('_')[5] + '.zip'
    newname = str(newname1)
    os.rename(os.path.join(p_dir, oldname), os.path.join(p_dir, newname))
    os.makedirs(p_dir, newname1)
```

but error is.. TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
What should I do?

Comment: Which line has the error?

Comment: Look at the function signature for makedirs: `os.makedirs(name, mode=511, exist_ok=False)` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html)

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: You are confusing `makedirs` and `mkdir`. We need to pass the `path` and `mode` in `mkdir` and `name` and `mode` in `makedirs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to use Python to unzip the zip file and save it in each folder.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71745500/i-want-to-use-python-to-unzip-the-zip-file-and-save-it-in-each-folder)

Comment: yes.. sorry ....

Answer (score 0):

The immediate error is that your `makedirs` invocation is wrong. If you pass in two arguments, the second argument should be a number which indicates the permissions of the directory; for example, `0o751` (decimal 489) indicates read+write+execute (7) for owner, read+execute (5) for group, and execute (1) for others. (Conventionally, these numbers are communicated in octal, because they map nicely to one digit per permission.)

However, you are also needlessly converting variables which are already strings to strings, and copying things which don't need to be copied.

It's also not clear why you split on `_`; your example image shows no file names with underscores in them, let alone then file names with five or more of them.  Per your problem description, I'm guessing you want to look for a `.zip` extension and remove it.

Try this:

```
import os
# import glob     # unused
# import zipfile  # unused
# import sys      # unused


p_dir =  './data/'

for file in os.listdir(p_dir):
    if file.endswith('.zip'):
        newname = file[:-4]
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(p_dir, newname))
```

Answer (score 0):

as per your code

```
newname1 = file.split('_')[5] + '.zip'
newname = str(newname1)
```

`newname1` and `newname` are the same

as per your code

```
os.makedirs(p_dir, newname1)
```

This is wrong code

You need to write

```
os.makedirs(os.path.join(p_dir, newname1))
```

But still you will get an error

There fore you need to remove `.zip` for `newname1`

may be like below

```
newname1 = file.split('_')[5]
newname = str(newname1) + '.zip'
```

So your final code will look like

```
import os
import glob
import zipfile
import sys


p_dir =  './data/'

for file in os.listdir(p_dir):
    file_name = file
    oldname = str(file_name)
    print(file)
    newname1 = file.split('_')[5]
    newname = str(newname1) + '.zip'
    os.rename(os.path.join(p_dir, oldname), 
    os.path.join(p_dir, newname))
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(p_dir, newname1))
```

But I don't understand the `_` split

Answer (score 0):

In `os.makedirs(path[, mode])` you can pass two parameters. `path` and `mode`(optional) and the error you get is because the `mode` should be an integer. And the default mode is `Oo777` in octal. Therefore you can use the following code to fix your problem.

```
import os
p_dir = './data'

for file in os.listdir(p_dir):
   newname = file[:-4]
   os.makedirs(os.path.join(p_dir, newname))
```

or

```
import os
p_dir = './data'

for file in os.listdir(p_dir):
   newname = file[:-4]
   os.makedirs(os.path.join(p_dir, newname), 0o777))
```